# How to insert separators between columns?

Tags: raku

I have columns in `@columns`:

```
my @columns =('column1', 'column2', 'column3');
```

and I have separators in `@separators`:

```
my @separators = (',', '|');
```

I want to insert the separators between columns, one by one:

```
column1,column2|column
```

my solution is:

```
(@columns »~» (|@separators,"")).join("")
```

Here I have three columns and two separators, and how about insert `N-1` separators between `N` columns?

Comment: You could try `say ((@columns Z @separators), @columns[*-1]).flat.join("")`

Comment: @HåkonHægland  Thanks, have fixed the typo ^_^

Comment: Do mean the case that `N` is different from `@columns.elems`?

Comment: @HåkonHægland `N` is equal  to `@columns.elems`, also equal to `@separators.elems +1 `

Comment: But  doesn't your proposed solution already work fine for that case?

Comment: `(@columns >>,>> @separators).map( |* )[0..*-2].join("")`

This works for any number of columns I think.

Comment: `@columns.reduce: { $^a ~ @separators[$++] ~ $^b};` or `@separators.push: "";
                                        say [~] @columns Z~ @separators;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that `@separators` has the right number of values, you could use [`roundrobin`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/roundrobin).

```perl6
roundrobin( @columns, @separators ).flat.join()
```

Answer (score 6):

So this should work for a any length of `@columns` or `@separators` :

First we use the `>>,>>` hyper operator to make a list of lists.

`(@columns >>,>> @separators)`

Which gives :

`[("column1", ","), ("column2", "|"), ("column3", ",")]`

Then we flatten this into a single list using a slip.

`(@columns >>,>> @separators).map( |* )`

Which gives:

`("column1", ",", "column2", "|", "column3", ",").Seq`

Then we get the array of all but the last value :

`(@columns >>,>> @separators).map(|*).head(*-1)`

For :

`("column1", ",", "column2", "|", "column3")`

And finally join it with nothing :

`(@columns >>,>> @separators).map(|*).head(*-1).join("")`

Final result :

`column1,column2|column3`

Changing the number of columns or separators will not make a difference.

Comment: I think `[^(*-1)]` would be clearer if written as `.head(*-1)`

Answer (score 0):

May be another solution:

```
my @columns =('column1', 'column2', 'column3');
my @separators = (',', '|');
sub sep { $^a ~@separators[$++] ~$^b};
say [[&sep]] @columns;

say [[&sep]] @columns; # but another call cause error


Use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context.
Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something     meaningful.
in sub sep at <unknown file> line 1
in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1

Use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context.
Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something  meaningful.
in sub sep at <unknown file> line 1
in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1

column1column2column3
```